# Why the element cannot be located in method function in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I already created a method to get the transaction ID but the element cannot be located. I cannot retrieve the ID in the web table because it shows an error that unable to locate the element. Besides, it will open another blank window.

This is the method to get the ID

```
public String getTransactionID(String ID) throws IOException {

    File src = new File("C:\\selenium\\ExcelData\\TestData.xlsx");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
    wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    XSSFSheet sh1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    String getValue = null;
    String TransactionID = null;
    for (int i = 0; i<=1000; i++) {
        if(sh1.getRow(i).getCell(0) != null)
        {
             getValue = sh1.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
        }

        if(getValue != null) {
            if(getValue.contains(ID)) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\selenium\\geckodriver-v0.23.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");

                WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                TransactionID = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td")).getText();
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(src);
                sh1.getRow(i).createCell(1).setCellValue(TransactionID);
                wb.write(fout);
                fout.close();

                break;
            }   
        }   

    }
    return TransactionID;
```

This is the line to call the method

```js
GetExcel transID = new GetExcel();
transID.getTransactionID("Transaction ID");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**

The issue lies in the below snippet:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

The will open up a new Firefox browser. That's why you saw a 'blank window' open up.

```
TransactionID = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td")).getText();
```

Immediately after that you're attempting to search for the element on the website. As you can imagine, attempting to find an element on a blank page will obviously throw you an error.

You need to navigate to the website first:

```
driver.get(your_url_here);
```

**Sidenotes**

Your xpath isn't ideal as it is too hardcoded -- if a new element is created in the website, your xpath will probably break. You should instead use a more dynamic approach that utilizes the element's DOM properties such as `id`:

```
//table[@id='xxx']//td
```

Documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp

In addition, your variable name `TransactionID` should be in lower caps, i.e. `transactionID`.